# Using the Linux kernel in my operating system

Tags: linux, operating-system

**PREFACE**

I tried to put as much effort and work into this question as I reasonably could, so if you could at least read it through, I would highly appreciate it; I, also, have tried researching this question, but I never seemed to find anything useful, in terms of anything that directly answered my question; I do not know if this is right place for this question, even though it is related to programming, it is more related to operating system development and the Linux kernel, and if there is a better place for this question that I am unaware of, please move it there; feel free to do whatever, edit the question if need be, I do not care, I just need an answer to this question, because this is stressing me out.

The following is some background on why I am asking this question; if you are uninterested, and if you just want to see what I am asking, then skip to the 'MY QUESTION' label; I thought that I would put this is here, so that anyone who is reading this question would know *why* I am asking this question.

**BACKGROUND**

I have recently begun setting up an operating system development project; and after I get some things ready, it will be only me working on it, as of right now, and I plan to write the whole thing (yes, I know it will take a whole lot of work, but I can try, right? :p), including the bootstrapping, the CLI, and most of what is necessary to have to either my own kernel or Linux kernel function; GUI and much more; granted, eventually I may end up having a team, but that is for the future.

**MY QUESTION**

My question, which is actually consists of three parts, and I narrowed them down to specifically those thee things, which are the following:

(1) If I were to build everything else, and use the Linux kernel as-is, and if I were to not tie the other parts of the system into the kernel, but use the kernel for I/O and system calls, would I be violating the GPL in any way, and would I think need to open source the rest of my code?

(2) If I were to only use the kernel for I/O and for system calls, but not have the code that *I* wrote actually interface with any kernel functions, would that still be considered linking?

(3) If I were to do the above, would that be considered a derived work, when I wrote everything else, but used Linux as the system's kernel?

All these legal issues are making my head spin and extremely confusing to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about copyright law.

Comment: This sort of question is a good fit for https://opensource.stackexchange.com/   Pretty sure you'll find the answer there already and not have to ask.

Comment: I knew it was a question for a lawyer because of the tl;dr first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. No
3. No

The linux kernel considers the system calls a boundary, and code that communicates with the kernel via system calls is not covered by the licensing of the kernel. So, the user space code you write is not a derivative work of the kernel.

There's also a set of header files provided by the kernel, collectively named the UAPI headers which you can use without having your code become a derivative work

This is covered at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/process/license-rules.html and https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/LICENSES/exceptions/Linux-syscall-note

If you need legal advice though, contact a lawyer.